# Alternating series limit question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose $b_n > 0$ for all $n\geq1$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}-1\right)>0,$$ show that the alternating series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n b_n$ converges.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to show that $\{b_n\}$ is decreasing and converging to zero.

Since the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}n\left(\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}-1\right)=a>0,
$$
there is an $n_0$, such that $n\ge n_0$ implies that
$$
\frac{a}{2}<n\left(\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}-1\right),
$$
and hence
$$
1+\frac{a}{2n}<\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}},
$$
and thus $b_n$ is strictly decreasing, and
$$
b_{n+1}<\frac{b_n}{1+\frac{a}{2n}}<\frac{b_{n_0}}{\prod_{k=n_0}^n(1+\frac{a}{2k})}\to 0,
$$
since $$
\prod_{k=n_0}^n\left(1+\frac{a}{2k}\right)>\frac{a}{2}\sum_{k=n_0}^n\frac{1}{k}\to\infty.
$$